# Configurações no VS2019 não permanecem

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Fiz isso no meu VS2019
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí altero o Nome da Origem(Name) e no Source eu colo o link. Acontece que depois de eu dar OK em todo esse processo, acontece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já desloguei a conta e coloquei a conta pessoal e continua a mesma coisa, ou seja, não mantém as configurações. Desinstalei o VS2019 e reinstalei e nada ainda. Por estar com pressa, perguntei aqui mesmo no site como fazer isso no Visual Code, porém a empresa me disse que prefere todos no Visual Studio e não me perguntem porque, pois não sei também.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema e quero aqui compartilhar para que outros que passarem por isso, possam ser ajudados também:

1. Primeiro, um erro bobo de minha parte: O VS2019 não estava em modo ADMIN.
2. O PATH da aplicação estava com um nome estranho, tipo, D#W21%2AZ&fg..... e por aí vai e apesar de estranho, era um nome grande. Renomeei para PFD e foi sem problemas.

Que sirva de exemplo para quem vir após.